# How to Simulate Button Click in Lightning Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

How i can simulate click on a multiple buttons from client side controller of the Lightning Aura Component?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please add some sort of markup/code to better understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to download attachments at URL. I can't share the code due to IP policy of the company. I know it can be done with <a> tag, however I need solution for mass download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the Element click method. Here's an example:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'some file url';
a.click();
```

Note that browsers will typically block this type of script unless the user clicks a button. You might not be able get a "mass downloader" working in any modern browser because of this restriction.

Comment: Can I loop through the urls and fire it within loop?

Comment: @ShohraiMuhamov You *can* write such code, but if it works will depend on browser settings and security settings.

Comment: Can I use same method to download audio files such as mp3 or wav, or is there another way of doing it for them?

Comment: Using for loop worked for mass download for me! Kudos @sfdcfox !